# Azure Functions JavaScript function.json route data binding with floats

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to use a JavaScript Azure Function data binding to Cosmos DB using a sqlQuery with a float parameter in the where clause.

Here is my binding definition from function.json:

Doesn't work, returns no results I believe because the lat/lon are treated as strings:

```
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "GetLoq/{lat:float}/{lon:float}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "doc",
      "databaseName": "%CosmosDBNAME%",
      "collectionName": "%CosmosCollectionNAME%",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c where c.location.coordinates = [{lat}, {lon}]",
      "connectionStringSetting": "DB",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
```

Works when I hard-code the values (for comparison):

```
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "GetLoq/{lat:float}/{lon:float}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "doc",
      "databaseName": "%CosmosDBNAME%",
      "collectionName": "%CosmosCollectionNAME%",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c where c.location.coordinates = [36.71, 3.25]",
      "connectionStringSetting": "DB",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query doesn't work because it searches for string value `["36.71", "3.25"]` instead of float.

There's an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2279) not solved yet.

> Route Constraints allow specifying datatypes for query string parameters on HttpTrigger route property. These constraints are only used to match the route.
>   When using binding parameters datatype is converted to strings.

We have to create a UDF `toFloat`(click more option icon beside collection > New UDF) to convert string to float first.

```
function stringToFloatUDF(input){
    return parseFloat(input);
}
```

Then modify sqlQuery with UDF.

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT * from c where c.location.coordinates = [udf.toFloat({lat}), udf.toFloat({lon})]",
```